# Inner Join Producing cartesian product

Tags: sql, oracle10g, inner-join

Looking at the 2 queries below, I assumed they would return the same result set but they're way off.  Why is the 2 query with the inner join producing so many records?  What am I doing wrong?  I've been staring at this a little too long and need a fresh pair of eyes to look at it.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  
FROM ZCQ Z
WHERE Z.QUOTE_CUSTOMER_ID IN (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID FROM CUST_ORDER)
-- returned 6,646 RECS

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM ZCQ Z
INNER JOIN CUST_ORDER CO ON zquote_customer_id = co.customer_id
-- returned 4,232,473 RECS
```

Please note these are Oracle 10g tables but have no FK or PK setup by the DBA.

Answer (score 1):

No, these will not generally return the same result.

- The first counts the number of rows in `ZCQ` that match a customer in `CUST_ORDER`.
- The second counts the total number of rows that match.  If there are duplicate customers in `CUST_ORDER`, then all duplicates will be counted.

You *could* get the same result using:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT z.zquote_customer_id) 
FROM ZCQ Z JOIN
     CUST_ORDER CO
     ON zquote_customer_id = co.customer_id;
```

But `IN` or `EXISTS` is probably more efficient than removing the duplicates *after* doing the match.